# How loop only videos in my youtube channel when embeded in the website

Tags: html

I am trying to embed YouTube video into my website. The challenge is, the video runs properly but when it completes it brings suggestions of others videos which are not in my channel.
Here is the code am trying to use `<iframe width="100%" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxxx"></iframe>`

I wanted it to loop only videos in my YouTube channel .

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Well, its in hand of youtube. If you want your videos to play, consider adding an end screen to your youtube video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your profile in URL which you added